# Copying attachments of sent mails in gnus

Tags: gnus, email, copy-paste, attachment

This is a very basic question. I often have to send the same attachments to different people so it would be convenient if I could copy them from my sent mails. I thought this would be very easy, since attachments in an unsent are described using a string that I should just be able to copypaste, but if I look up a sent mail, the attachment text is collapsed:

```
[3. test --- application/pdf; test.pdf]...
```

I tried to expand the line using tab, but it didn't work. I also found the command `gnus-mime-copy-part`, but it just opens the attachment in a new buffer. How can I simply copy my attachments into a new mail?